# Move Graphics axis or get a sub-graphics at an arbitrary point?

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

I often need to draw items in a `Graphics` object and the way I've been doing it is to have a function `DrawItem` that receives the `Graphics` object and an `offsetX` and `offsetY` parameters, which determine at which point the item will be drawn.

The problem is that the code inside `DrawItem` would look a lot better if there would be a method in `Graphics` that would give me a version of the Graphics where the X and Y axis zeroes are at some other point, something like `myGraphics.DisplacedGraphics(offsetX, offsetY)`. This way I would just pass this `Graphics` objects to my `DrawItem` method which wouldn't need to receive the other two parameters. Is there such function or what's the closest thing?

**Edit:** On the meanwhile this is what I wrote, but seems like such a basic requirement I still hope there already exists such functionality (I'd still need to add a bunch of methods but these are all I need for now) (note the `DisplacedCanvas` method):

```
public class Canvas
{
    private readonly Graphics _Graphics;
    private readonly int _OriginX = 0;
    private readonly int _OriginY = 0;

    public Canvas(Graphics graphics, int originX, int originY)
    {
        _Graphics = graphics;
        _OriginX = originX;
        _OriginY = originY;
    }

    public Canvas(Graphics graphics) : this(graphics, 0, 0) { }

    public SizeF MeasureString(string text, Font font)
    {
        return _Graphics.MeasureString(text, font);
    }

    public void FillRectangle(Brush brush, int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        _Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, _OriginX + x, _OriginY + y, width, height);
    }

    public void DrawString(string s, Font font, Brush brush, float x, float y)
    {
        _Graphics.DrawString(s, font, brush, _OriginX + x, _OriginY + y);
    }

    public Canvas DisplacedCanvas(int x, int y)
    {
        return new Canvas(_Graphics, _OriginX + x, _OriginY + y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the [`TranslateTransform()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a1d65f4.aspx) will do what you're asking for.

> The origin is typically the upper-left-hand corner of the drawing surface. The translation operation consists of multiplying the transformation matrix by a matrix whose translation part is the dx and dy parameters. This method applies the translation by prepending the translation matrix to the transformation matrix.

So if you want the new origin to be at 100, 50, then you would first call `graphics.TranslateTransform(100, 50)` before drawing your image.